# `NOT` is Not A Macro But A Function in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I don't know why `NOT` is defined as a **function** but a **macro**.  
I've heard that function call may be cache-unfriendly.

Will it be better if `NOT` is a **macro**？  
The only reason I can think of is that a `NOT` function can be passed as value by adding `#'`.

Comment: choosing between a macro and a function to implement something is preferably not based on performance, in fact "function call may be cache-unfriendly" is not really the way to go with optimizations: don't avoid using basic things like functions because they "may" have bad performance (this is not true generally); maybe if you allocate too many closures at runtime you can have bad runtime performance but a reasonable use should not be a problem

Comment: The best way to get good performance is to choose a good algorithm for the problem at hand. Worrying about  cache-unfriendliness e.g. should come after you have an implementation, you have found the implementation to be just a bit shy of your desired performance goals, you have profiled the code to find out where it is spending most of its time, you have determined that at least one of the "hot" spots is caused by poor cache performance and you have identified *which* function (or functions) contribute to that.

Comment: (cont.) If you have fallen far short of your performance goals, such micro-optimizations will  generally not be useful: you have to find a better algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`not` has the semantics of a function: its argument is evaluated perfectly normally (unlike, say, `and` and so on).  It should therefore *be* a function: macros should be used only for things which cannot semantically be functions.

Making `not` a function has benefits: simply because it is a function you don't need to write your own version every time you need a function with the semantics of `not`.  Making `not` a function also has zero cost since the semantics of CL leave a compiler or interpreter entirely free to never actually call the function but rather generate inline code.

Indeed you can see, for instance, in the SBCL sources that this is happening: in `src/code/pred.lisp` you will find

```
(defun not (object)
  "Return T if X is NIL, otherwise return NIL."
  (not object))
```

You can do this yourself, pretty much:

```
(declaim (inline neg))

(defun neg (x)
  (if x nil t))
```

(And if you are really feeling your oats define a compiler macro as well, although I can't see any strong reason to do that here.)